# Geometric probability; circle doesn't intersect with lines

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

On a plane covered with parallel lines, which distances are alternately 2 and 3, circle with diameter 1 is thrown. What is the probability that the circle doesn't intersect with any of the lines?

If the circle is between two lines which distance is 2: if the circle doesn't intersect lines I will have in total length 1 between circle and lines. Also If the circle is between two lines which distance is 3 and if it doesn't intersect with lines I will have in total length 2 between circle and lines. When I add 2 and 3 the, distances between lines, I will get 5 which is the total outcome. And when I add 1 and 2 I will get the desired outcome. Finally, the probability is $\frac{3}{5}$. I am not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Yes, the probability is $\frac35$. Instead of intersecting circle of diameter $1$ with lines of zero width, one can look at the equivalent problem of intersecting a point with lines of width $1$. It is clear the "thickened" lines cover $\frac25$ of the plane, so the probability is $1 - \frac25 = \frac35$.